# Reroute URL containing ".." when on localhost in tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, web, url-rewriting

I'm using Tomcat 8 and [UrlReWriteFiler](http://www.tuckey.org/urlrewrite/). I have a strange request and without getting into too much detail I need to enable tomcat running on a local machine to route `localhost:8080/project/..` to `localhost:8080/project/data`.

I'm trying to get a hello world example running. I realize this is a non-standard requirement but the issue comes from an application that runs plugins in a different environment looking for a file in a folder relative to the current folder `".."`.

I'm looking to enable the development of a plugin on a local machine by routing anything from `localhost:8080/project/..` to `localhost:8080/project/data`.

**urlwrite.xml:**

```
<urlrewrite>
    <rule>
        <name>Dev Development</name>
        <condition name="host" operator="equal">^localhost:8080/.*/..</condition>
        <from>^localhost:8080/(.*)/\.\.$</from>
        <to type="permanent-redirect" last="true">http://localhost:8080/$1/data</to>
    </rule>
</urlrewrite>
```

**web.xml:**

```
<web-app id="simple" version="2.4">

  <filter>
      <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
      <filter-class>org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
      <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
      <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
  </filter-mapping> 

   <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>hello.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list> 
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Hello</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>Hello</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Hello</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/data</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: `..` indicates the parent folder. Therefore, `localhost:8080/project/..` is interpreted as `localhost:8080/`

Comment: @vivianig I realize that, I'm trying to override that behavior. Is it possible?

Comment: I'm afraid that both `..` and `.` are resolved in the URI before the forwarding process, therefore there is no way to intercept that. Have a look here http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-3.3

Comment: @vivianig drat! I was hoping there was a work around. Even if I'm making an AJAX call, there is no work around? I realize this is a different question.

Comment: @vivianig I'm contemplating routing localhost:8080 to localhost:8080/project/data by default

Comment: I'm not sure I get what you mean with the AJAX call, could you give me some sort of example?
Routing the root url isn't a great idea usually, anyone connecting to the URL would get rerouted. It works if you don't have any index page, otherwise it would break everythign.